# How to send reset password token via a single link

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a list of users in a `ListView` CBV and want to add a "reset password" link that will send an email with a reset password token to that user with one click (as the `auth_views` are currently set up to after you submit a request via a form).

For example:

```
<td>{{ user.email }}</td>
<td><a href="{% url 'reset_link' user.pk %}">Reset password</a></td>
```

I am using the CBV `auth_views` so know I could reset this user's password manually via redirecting to a form and using Django's inbuilt `auth_views.PasswordResetView`. However as I already have the `user.pk` I just want a link that instantly sends the relevant email.

Is there a way to send the email using `user.pk` via a single link if I already know the `pk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick *hack* can be:

**urls.py**:

```
path('<int:user_pk>/my_password_reset/', views.MyPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='my_password_reset'),
```

**views.py**:

```
class MyPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs.get('user_pk'))
        return {'data': {'email': user.email}}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```